# main.dart file cant start "gradle error, exit code 1"

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, emulation

When I try to start my `main.dart` I get an error called

> "Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1".

I'm running the default code when you create a new project with `flutter create "name"`. When I run `flutter doctor` I get no errors, so I don't know what could be the problem. Some people said not enough space on disk. But I have about 50gbs left. I'm running on the android emulator with the pixel 4. Yesterday everything worked fine and today I wanted to create a new project, and now it doesn't work anymore. Even though I didn't change anything in the emulator settings or the VS Code settings/file.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you share the complete exception message?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the problem where the default gradle is outdated and sucj you need to update it, if you are using android studio, when opening a gradle file in teh top right corner it will say `open for editing in android studio` , click on it and it will open a new window, in the terminal run `gradlew` or `gradlew upgrade`.

also the flutter team said they were working on it, so try to update flutter to the latest version using the command `flutter upgrade`

Comment: well im working in vscode. im running the latest flutter version already. checked that. i run `./gradlew --upgrade-dependencies`  but still doesnt work.